# Delphi - Maximize a form to a particular screen

Tags: delphi, forms, maximize-window

Quite a simple one i would think, but i need to be able to Maximize a form to a particular screen. Cant seem to find any Delphi specific info.

I can remember the forms position over subsequent application loads. However, when i restore the position, then call `WindowState := wsMaximized`, the form moves to the other screen! (i do have other forms also visible on that screen - it appears its maximizing to the 'active screen')

So i need a function like so:

```
procedure Maximize(const aScreenIndex : Integer);
begin
 if aScreenIndex < Screen.MonitorCount then
   //Maximize to that screen
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intercept the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message and adjust the coordinates inside its `MINMAXINFO` structure as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Set Form.Position to poDesigned at design time
In Form.FormShow or your Maximize procedure:

```
procedure Maximize(const aScreenIndex : Integer);
begin
  if aScreenIndex < Screen.MonitorCount then
  begin 
   //Maximize to that screen
    Myform.Left := screen.Monitors[aScreenIndex ].Left;
    Myform.WindowState := wsMaximized;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Genius! This solves the `how to position a form in a additional monitor problem` although in a maximized form. The problem had something to do with hide/show and this solved it as I put the medicine in onShow of the form.