# How to make main form appear in 2nd monitor

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi 10 and I have two monitors when I create default vcl application and run the application the main form always appear in the first monitor is there a way to make it appear in the second monitor by default ?

This may be option in the IDE or property or code

Thanks

Comment: *By default*? No. In code? Yes.

Comment: Generally I would suggest that you don't do this. Let the user place the form but remember where they left it and put it back there next time they show it. Your design takes control away from the user.

Comment: Also this design fails when the second monitor doesn't exist.    Thus as David states, the common pattern is to remember your form X,Y position when it was closed, and if that is still a visible area on a visible monitor you can use it as the initial position when you restore. There is a quite a bit of code involved in allowing form position to be saved if you want to be careful and not make the form appear somewhere invisible to the user when monitor layouts change.

Comment: I'm your user. I have 6 monitors, I want it to show in the top-right one by default. But you're forcing it to always show on the bottom-left.

Comment: Not tested main form but additional forms can be displayed on different monitors (in maximized form though). Check this question . No need to take pains of calculating/offsetting coordinates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368276/delphi-maximize-a-form-to-a-particular-screen

Answer (score 11):

`TForm` has a [`DefaultMonitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.DefaultMonitor) property that is set to `dmActiveForm` by default.  When no Form is active, the primary monitor is used.  However, there is no way to set the `DefaultMonitor` to the second monitor specifically.

`TForm` also has a [`Monitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Monitor) property, but for whatever reason it is read-only.

So, to display a `TForm` on a specific monitor, you can locate the desired monitor in the global [`TScreen.Monitors[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Monitors) list, and then either:

1. manually set the Form's `Left`/`Top` properties to an X/Y coordinate that is within the bounds of the monitor's [`BoundsRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TMonitor.BoundsRect) or [`WorkareaRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TMonitor.WorkareaRect) property.
2. pass the monitor to the Form's public [`MakeFullyVisible()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.MakeFullyVisible) method.

Comment: *TForm also has a Monitor property, but for whatever reason it is read-only* - I am not surprised about this property being readonly. What should the form do if you set this property? I can not imagine what

Comment: @SirRufo it could do the same thing that `MakeFullyVisible()` alrwady does - move the Form to the specified monitor

Comment: Maybe, but MakeFullyVisible do more than only change the monitor and the name of the method tells you that. Just changing the property can cause some unwanted behaviour. I would have implemented it also as readonly

Answer (score 2):

I've two monitor of 1600px width. My primary monitor is on the right, so, for place a form on the left I've to pass a negative value for his `Left` property.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // (3200 / 2 = + 1600) * -1 = -1600
  Left := (Screen.DesktopWidth div 2) * -1;
end;
```

The result is `-1600` that means the most to the left of my secondary monitor.

You also can get the "most Left" position of each monitor by calling `Screen.Monitors[i].Left`, something like this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  lMens: string;
begin
  lMens := '';
  for I := 0 to Screen.MonitorCount - 1 do
  begin
    lMens := lMens + ' | '
             + Format('%d - Left = %d', [i, Screen.Monitors[i].Left])
  end;
  ShowMessage(lMens);
end;
```

I hope that help's you.