Multiple monitors manipulation in a Delphi 11 application
I am building the following simple application in Delphi 11 for use with a dual monitor computer. The app just has a form with a button on it.
On clicking the button, the form should be displayed on the other screen and vice versa. I use the VCL method TForm.MakeFullyVisible to make the form fully visible on the specified monitor.
If the form has property windowstate = wsNormal it works ok
If it has windowstate = wsMaximized:

it displays fine on the default display
but on the second display only the lower part of the form's caption bar is displayed and nothing else

What can I do to make the form appear maximized and fully visible on both screens?
The form (.dfm) file:
object Form17: TForm17
  Left = 551
  Top = 291
  Caption = 'Form17'
  ClientHeight = 442
  ClientWidth = 628
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poDesigned
  WindowState = wsMaximized
  TextHeight = 15
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 112
    Top = 80
    Width = 34
    Height = 15
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 384
    Top = 24
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end

the code (.pas) file:
unit Unit17;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,  Vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm17 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form17: TForm17;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var monitorNo :integer = 0; // EDITED FROM const to var as Ken White suggested

procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     monitorNo := (monitorNo + 1) mod screen.MonitorCount;
     label1.Caption := intToStr(monitorNo);
     MakeFullyVisible(screen.Monitors[monitorNo]);
end;

end.


Why are you hashing writeable typed constant global variables?

Take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368276/delphi-maximize-a-form-to-a-particular-screen

@Brian.  I have already implemented this approach but I would like to see if there is any error in using the makeFullyVisible procedure

@KenWhite. The procedure definition is: MakeFullyVisible(AMonitor: TMonitor = null), so I pass the monitor I want the form to show. It is not right? I don't find the use of writable variables bad, but helpful. Besides, why does Delphi give this possibility?

Nope, you're right. I didn't look before I posted. Writable variables are not the issue. Writeable constants are. Do you not understand what the word constant means? It means unchanging. So why are you deciarling a variable that says it cannot be changed, but then allowing it to be changeable? It makes your code hard to read, because you can never be sure if what you're reading is actually what exists. If you need a changeable value, don't use a constant, use a var. As far as why Delphi allows it, it was left in only  for compatibility with Turbo Pascal from the 1980s.

@KenWhite. Ok. i fixed const to var. But my main problem is why makeFullyVisible doesn't work properly when the form is in wsMaximized state.

I don't have access to Delphi 11 on my home machine (with dual-monitors).
And i don't have access to dual-monitors on my work machine (operating remotely).
But looking at the implementation of TCustomForm.MakeFullyVisible it looks like it may be susceptible to dpi changes:
procedure TCustomForm.MakeFullyVisible(AMonitor: TMonitor);
var
  ALeft: Integer;
  ATop: Integer;
begin
  if AMonitor = nil then
    AMonitor := Monitor;
  ALeft := Left;
  ATop := Top;
  if Left + Width > AMonitor.Left + AMonitor.Width then
    ALeft := AMonitor.Left + AMonitor.Width - Width;
  if Left < AMonitor.Left then
    ALeft := AMonitor.Left;
  if Top + Height > AMonitor.Top + AMonitor.Height then
    ATop := AMonitor.Top + AMonitor.Height - Height;
  if Top < AMonitor.Top then
    ATop := AMonitor.Top;
  SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, Width, Height);
end;

It's reading:

Monitor.Width
Monitor.Height

Which may not be accurate when you have:

non-standard DPI
different DPI between "main" display and alternate displays

Unless your application is manifested that indicate that it understands non-96 dpi, or manifested that it understands different, per-monitor, dpi, then the values of TMonitor.Width and TMonitor.Height cannot be trusted.
I suggest you manifest your application to be "per-monitor" dpi aware, and then forget the VCL, and use the GetMonitorInfo Windows function directly to get the rcWork work area, and then set the top-left-bottom-right of your form to that.

I realized that MakeFullyVisible is useless, so I wrote a replacement that works fine even monitor's size or DPI differs.
procedure TmainForm.MakeFullyVisible(monitorNo : integer);
begin
 with mainForm do begin
     top := 0;
     left := screen.Monitors[monitorNo].left;
     width := screen.Monitors[monitorNo].Width;
     height := screen.Monitors[monitorNo].Height;
 end;

end;

But this function's name, MakeFullyVisible doesn't describe what the function actually does. MakeFullyVisible should move a window, not resize it.

@AndreasRejbrand. But it moves AND resizes the window making sure it fits the whole screen making it fully visible on the new monitor.

Why not using Screen.Monitors[monitorNo].Top? That code won't work everywhere (think of people stacking monitors).
